# Задача на массивы Java

Tags: java, массивы

По заданию нужно решить следующую задачу: Дан массив размера `N`. Вставить элемент с нулевым значением перед минимальным и после максимального элемента массива.
Решил задачу следующим образом:

```
Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
int n = in.nextInt();
int[] A;
A = new int[n];
int i;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    A[i] = in.nextInt();
}

int amin = 0, amax = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    if (A[amin] > A[i]) {
        amin = i;
    }
    if (A[amax] < A[i]) {
        amax = i;
    }
}
System.out.println("Min = " + A[amin]);
System.out.println("Max = " + A[amax]);
if (amax > amin) 
    amax++;
n++;
for (i = n - 1; i >= amin; --i)
    A[i] = A[i - 1];
A[amin] = 0;
n++;
for (i = n - 1; i > amax + 1; --i)
    A[i] = A[i - 1];
A[amax + 1] = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    System.out.print(A[i]);
```

Но по итогу появляется ошибка переполнения массива (максимальный и минимальный элемент находится верно). Прочитал, что на языке Java массивы не изменяемые и нужно как-то их копировать и создавать новые. Как можно это реализовать и решить эту задачу? Заранее большое спасибо!

Comment: Или что-то не то прочитал, или не так понял. Массивы - изменяемые. Неизменяема длина массива.

Comment: Да, именно это и имел в виду, но не то написал. Длина не изменяема

Comment: Создать новый массив длиной на 2 больше и заполнить

Answer (score 1):

```
//read the values from users input
String[] array = scanner.nextLine().split("\\s+");

//get min number with help of stream api (java 8+)
int min = Arrays.asStream(array)
.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).min();

//the same as previous but gettin max number
int max = Arrays.asStream(array)
.mapToInt(Integer::parseInt).max();

//create the list
ArrayList<Integer> list = Arrays.asStream(array).collect(Collectors.toList());

//getting indexes
int minIndex=list.indexOf(min);
int maxIndex=list.indexOf(max);

//insert into list by their places
list.add(minIndex, 0);//zero is a number to insert it may be everything
list.add(maxIndex, 0);

//map your list to array
int[] array = list.stream().toArray () ;
```

Comment: В Вашей реализации есть ошибка. Так как мы сначала находим индексы максимального и минимального элементов, то при вставке минимального элемента позиция максимального могла сдвинуться. Также ноль нужно вставить после максимального и получается нужно использовать индекс `maxIndex + 1`.

Answer (score 0):

Юзай `ArrayList`, а если надо будет переделать в массив:

```
list.stream().toArray()
```

Comment: А можете отправить пример кода как это реализовывать, просто не совсем понятно. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Вот один из вариантов кода:

```
package com.somepackage;

import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.stream.IntStream;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner in =
                new Scanner(System.in);
        int n = in.nextInt();
        int[] array =
                IntStream.range(0, n)
                        .map(i -> in.nextInt())
                        .toArray();

        int minIndex =
                getMaxIndex(array);
        System.out.println("Min = " + array[minIndex]);
        array = insert(array, minIndex, 0);

        int maxIndex =
                getMinIndex(array);
        System.out.println("Max = " + array[maxIndex]);
        array = insert(array, maxIndex + 1, 0);

        System.out.println("Result = " + Arrays.toString(array));
    }

    public static int getMaxIndex(
            int[] array) {
        return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                .reduce((i, j) -> array[i] > array[j] ? j : i)
                .getAsInt();
    }

    public static int getMinIndex(
            int[] array) {
        return IntStream.range(0, array.length)
                .reduce((i, j) -> array[i] < array[j] ? j : i)
                .getAsInt();
    }

    public static int[] insert(
            int[] array,
            int index,
            int element) {
        int[] result =
                new int[array.length + 1];
        System.arraycopy(
                array, 0, result, 0, index);
        System.arraycopy(
                array, index, result, index + 1, array.length - index);
        result[index] = element;
        return result;
    }
}
```

Пример:

```
5
5
4
3
2
1
Min = 1
Max = 5
Result = [5, 0, 4, 3, 2, 0, 1]
```